# Creating custom stemmer for hinglish in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am new to elasticsearch. I want to create a custom analyzer in elasticsearch, with custom filters and custom stemmers. I know that ElasticSearch is built upon lucene, and in lucene, custom stemmer support is there. But, I am not able to find any example, which shows custom analyzer/stemmer implementation in lucene and integration of the same in elasticsearch.

Apologizing for bad english. Thanks in advance.

> Edit 1

What I want is Hinglish Stemmer, which will transform following inputs to given below outputs:-

- **Rama, Raam, Ram  =>  ram**
- **Sachin, Sacheen, Sachina, Sacheena, Sachhin => sachin**
- **Kuldeep, Kooldeep, Kuldip, Kooldipa => kuldip**

Comment: Did you have alook at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html

Comment: @Richa, I did have a look at articles, mentioned by you. As I have mentioned in my question, I want to create custom stemmer for hinglish, which will stem "Rama", "Raam", "Ram" to "ram" and integrate it with elasticsearch. I am not able to find any good link, which can help me out.

Comment: a related plugin: https://www.rosette.com/fuzzy-search-names-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: You should have a look to the different Token filters, for example in your case, creating a custom Stemmer as shown here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-override-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after several hiccups, I was finally able to create implementation of hinglish-stemmer. It's available at following link :-

https://github.com/Mangu-Singh-Rajpurohit/hinglish-stemmer/

Comment: how would you ensure that the stemmer doesn't affect the English words?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to write a simple answer, let me know if you have any question.

First step: Create the custom_stemming file (here "custom_stems.txt"), like the following, and place it into the config folder (I put it under "config/analysis/custom_stems.txt"):

```
rama => ram
raam => ram
sachin => sachin
sacheen => sachin
sachina => sachin
sacheena => sachin
kuldeep => kuldip
kooldeep => kuldip
kooldipa => kuldip
```

Create then an index with an adequate mapping (I use the mapping from this example, you can create other analyzer, the only important part here is the "custom_stems" stemmer):

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "custom_stems"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "custom_stems" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer_override",
                    "rules_path" : "analysis/custom_stems.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test that it works:

```
GET /my_index/_analyze
{
  "text": ["Rama"],
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

You should see in the output:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "ram",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that i used:

- Elasticsearch 5.3.2
- Kibana 5.0.1

Comment: Mentioning all possible keywords in a file doesn't look like a good solution. Is there any other better scalable solution ? Moreover, I have already devised the algorithm, which can perform given above transformation on the input. I just need to know, how can I fit that java algorithm in elasticsearch infrastructure.

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit I see, for now what I could imagine is creating this file and updating from your program, and updating the indices settings using this custom stemmer as you add new value into the stems file. Perhaps it could work as well writing an ES plugin, however the documentation is pretty scarce at best.

Comment: I was also thinking on the same lines. Can you give me a link to good example/tutorial for the implementation of custom analyzer plugin in ES ?

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit Unfortunately, as the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugin-authors.html) says, the only thing you can do is looking at plugins already created to get information on how to do it. However, there are several plugins that were made for custom analyzers, you have a list [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis.html) and you can find easily their associated githubs

Comment: I have created my own stemmer, which works fine. Can you have a look at it and suggest recommendations ?